# Не отправляется кросс-доменный ajax-запрос

Tags: php, ajax

Есть ajax-запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://<?php echo getDomain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']); ?>/engine/search.php',
    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    crossDomain: true,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        data:data
    }
});
```

А на стороне сервера работает скрипт, проверяющий, был ли отправлен запрос посредством ajax:

```
<?php
$search_data = session_name("search_data");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.skytickets.ga');
session_start();
require('functions.php');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://search." . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Origin");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
if(isAjax()) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    if(isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
        if(!preg_match('/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/', $data['from']) && !preg_match('/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/', $data['to'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            die('Bad IATA codes provided');
        }
        if(!validateDate($data['there']) && !validateDate($data['thence'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            die('Bad date format provided');
        }
        if(!preg_match('/^[1-9]*$/', $data['adults']) && !preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $data['teens']) && !preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $data['kids'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            die('Bad passengers data provided');
        }
        $_SESSION['search_data'] = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        echo $_SESSION['search_data'];
        die();
    }
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('Access denied');
}
?>
```

Функция isAjax:

```
function isAjax() {
    return !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}
```

Перепроверил код 1000 раз, перечитал политику CORS 1000 раз и всё равно не могу понять, почему это не работает. Получаю ошибки **OPTIONS 403 (Forbidden)** и **XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP    status code 403**.

Comment: А оно так и не будет работать - думаете зря люди пишут прокси для пересылки запросов на другой домен? Вам лучше использовать или JSONP, или писать этот самый прокси, благо они размером в несколько строк.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov какие прокси?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin речь видимо идет о создании на стороне своего сервера пхп-скрипта, который будет выполнять нужные запросы к удаленному серверу. А к этому своему уже обращаться через ajax.

Comment: Почитайте методы реализации вашей задумки тут - http://jquery-howto.blogspot.ru/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html

Comment: @DanielProtopopov хм, насколько я понимаю, при помощи проксирующего скрипта можно загрузить данные. А передать их другому скрипту можно?

Comment: Конечно можно, серверный скрипт сделает то, что вы в нем напишите.